# Zerobrane dark mode howto

Tags: zerobrane

How to I activate dark mode in Zerobrane v1.9? If it is linked to the OS's dark mode setting, is there a way to force it on (I'm win7), or otherwise customize the colors of the filetree and outline windows?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question and it took me weeks to figure it out. So, I am answering the question for every Lua dev here.

To change ZeroBrane's Theme, just do the following:

1. Head over to ZeroBraneStudio\cfg
2. Right click on scheme-picker.lua
3. Open With: -> ZeroBrane.exe (yes, the program executable).
4. It opens up Zero Brane with a Lua file opened. Just click any Theme you want from that list, for example where it says [monokai].

That's it! The theme changes immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can follow the instructions in [the Color Scheme section](https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-styles-color-schemes#color-schemes) (or check [this FAQ answer](https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-faq#how-to-change-the-color-scheme-in-the-editor)). Keep in mind that some of the sub-components on the page take their colors from the OS theme (like the toolbar and the window borders) and will remain light even when the color of the editor and the filetree panels is dark.

When the OS dark mode setting is enabled, then the dark color scheme is selected automatically, but you can still set it to the one you prefer the same way as described in the previous paragraph.